# How to press and drag to select a group of ToggleButtons with Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am hoping to implement some drag-select functionality to a grid of buttons in a GUI. I want to achieve something similar to a drag selection box on desktop operating systems. One press and drag should be able to toggle a group of toggle buttons of arbitrary size. Can I accomplish this with Kivy?

All I can seem to find is [drag and drop](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.drag.html) functionality or [multi-select](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.compoundselection.html) of buttons by holding the shift key but not the exact functionality I am looking for.

Ideally the app could remember which group of toggle buttons were toggled by which specific drags by the user. Please see my attached image. Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

[image]

Here is my code so far:
**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton 

class ButtonGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(10 * 10):
            b = ToggleButton(text = str(i))
            self.add_widget(b)

class mainApp(App):
    pass

mainApp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
ButtonGridLayout:
    rows: 10
    cols: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a fairly complex coding exercise. But here are some hints to get you started.

1. If you want to drag and drop `Buttons` in a `Layout`, you probably don't want to use `GridLayout`, as that `Layout` does its own positioning of its children. Something a bit more flexible, like a `FloatLayout` will likely work better.
2. You can use `on_touch_down()`, `on_touch_move()`, and `on_touch_up()` methods in your `Layout` to draw and save a selection `Rectangle`.
3. You can use the `pos` and `size` of the `Buttons` to compare to the `Rectangle` and determine which `Buttons` have been selected, and save them in a list.
4. You can then use the same methods (as in hint #2) to drag and drop the list of selected `Buttons`
5. You will need to distinguish selection touches from drag and drop touches from the basic `Button` touches, in the `on_touch` methods. The `touch` object has a `button` attribute that tells which mouse button was pressed and can be used for some of this. You may need to bind keyboard events so that you can require, for example, holding the `ctrl` button down while making the selection. And then, perhaps, require using the right mouse button to do the actual drag and drop.
6. The drag and drop of a list of selected `Buttons` can be accomplished in an `on_touch_move()` method by just adding the `touch.dpos` to the `pos` of each selected `Button`.
7. Also note that you cannot use `pos_hint` in the `Buttons` as that will over-ride any `pos` change that you make as a result of the dragging.